# How to find hotspot points when an image is rotated by different angle?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, rotation, image-rotation

I have 36 images of the same car, each one rotated by ~10 degrees. Now, I need to show the new position of any hotspots marked on the image when they are rotated by 10 degrees. I tried using the below formula but it's not giving the right coordinates.

```
function rotate(x, y, xm, ym, a) {
    var cos = Math.cos,
    sin = Math.sin,

    a = a * Math.PI / 180, 
                     
    xr = (x - xm) * cos(a) - (y - ym) * sin(a)   + xm,
    yr = (x - xm) * sin(a) + (y - ym) * cos(a)   + ym;

    return [xr, yr];
}

rotate(526, 327, 640, 379, 10);
```

The original image size is: **1280x758**.

I visualized the images using opencv, below is the result:

```
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
x,y = (526,327)
image = cv2.circle(img, (x,y), radius=5, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

[image: Image 1 Hotspot at: 526,327]
Image 1 Hotspot(Red circle) at: 526,327

[image]
Image 2 Hotspot after rotating by 10 deg at: 536,307

Original Images are here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIYYa.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5zrU.jpg

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: We see car and rotating circle "by angle", so circle is tranformed to ellipse, and car elements are moving on distinct ellipses depending on distance to rotation axis and on height from the floor

Comment: This is a full 3D problem, which you cannot solve with the 2D rotation formula.